# Displaying motd with Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, motd

I'm trying to display on a motd user's detail (the user and the actual date)

Here is the step i take so far:

`sudo nano /etc/update-motd.d/00-welcome   #(script)`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Welcome user: ${USER}. Today is $(date)"  #(save the file)
```

`sudo chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/00-welcome`

But after a successful login the motd do not appear. What should i try instead?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read ALL of `man update-motd`? Near the end, it says:

```
   Scripts should emit a blank line before output, and end with a  newline
   character.  For instance:
```

So, change your script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "Welcome user: ${USER}. Today is $(date)"
```